# Belize with two small children

Tags: children, beaches, belize, ruins

I'd like to visit Belize in January with my family (2 adults, one child of 2.5 yrs, one infant of 8 months) ideally to spend some time on the beach (Ambergris Caye?) and a day or two gawping at Maya ruins. Does anyone have experience of travelling in this part of the world with small children?
The sites I've seen all feature rather expensive resorts. Is it possible to stay near a nice, safe beach on a budget? Is dragging two small children round the jungle feasible? I.e. are the ruins accessible within a few hours and without long treks?

EDIT: Perhaps I should have been more specific: can anyone recommend somewhere reasonably-priced for me and my family to stay while we visit Belize to do this?

Comment: I don't really see much of a question here... I've also never been to Belize, but I have traveled extensively in Mexico and Guatemala, and I can say that having small children never stops the locals from visiting such places. Latin Americans often have half a dozen children, and take them everywhere with them--including climbing Mayan ruins, and visiting the beach.

Comment: This is quite a bit broader to be answerable.  On top of this if you're asking about recommendations for accomodations you should include a budget limitations.

Comment: @user13190 I've been to Cahal Pech, which would be easily accessible for children. Other than that, I don't know.